# Column concatenation in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, concatenation

I have 2 data frames with uneven index:

[image]

[image]

I wanna combine these 2 data frames, `df1` and `df2`, into `df3`, but there I couldn't do it with the below code:

```
df3 = pd.concat(df1,df2,axis=1)
```

Please, help: how to concatenate?

I want to arrive at this data frame:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need same index values in both `Dataframe`s for align, so use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True` for default unique indices:

```
new = pd.concat([df1.reset_index(drop=True),df2.reset_index(drop=True)],axis=1)
```

Another solution, if same length of indices:

```
df2.index = df1.index
new = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
```

**Sample**:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({x: pd.Series(range(4)).astype(str).radd(x) for x in list('ABCD')})
print (df1)
    A   B   C   D
0  A0  B0  C0  D0
1  A1  B1  C1  D1
2  A2  B2  C2  D2
3  A3  B3  C3  D3

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'E':['E0','E1','E2','E3']}, index=[4,5,6,7])
print (df2)
    E
4  E0
5  E1
6  E2
7  E3

new = pd.concat([df1.reset_index(drop=True),df2.reset_index(drop=True)],axis=1) 
print (new)
    A   B   C   D   E
0  A0  B0  C0  D0  E0
1  A1  B1  C1  D1  E1
2  A2  B2  C2  D2  E2
3  A3  B3  C3  D3  E3
```

---

This method is more general, so if need new columns with possible same columns names is possible add parameter `keys` and then flatten `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['E0','E1','E2','E3']}, index=[4,5,6,7])
print (df2)
    A
4  E0
5  E1
6  E2
7  E3

new=pd.concat([df1.reset_index(drop=True),df2.reset_index(drop=True)],axis=1, keys=('a','b')) 
new.columns = new.columns.map('_'.join)
print (new)
  a_A a_B a_C a_D b_A
0  A0  B0  C0  D0  E0
1  A1  B1  C1  D1  E1
2  A2  B2  C2  D2  E2
3  A3  B3  C3  D3  E3
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael . It helps

Comment: @AhamedMoosa - Glad can help!

Answer (score 2):

#### `pd.DataFrame.join` + `pd.DataFrame.set_index`

```
df1.join(df2.set_index(df1.index))

    A   B   C   D   E
0  A0  B0  C0  D0  E0
1  A1  B1  C1  D1  E1
2  A2  B2  C2  D2  E2
3  A3  B3  C3  D3  E3
```

---

#### `pd.DataFrame.assign`

```
df1.assign(**df2.to_dict('l'))

    A   B   C   D   E
0  A0  B0  C0  D0  E0
1  A1  B1  C1  D1  E1
2  A2  B2  C2  D2  E2
3  A3  B3  C3  D3  E3
```

**How it works**

`assing` takes keyword arguments where the key is the name of the new column and the values are what is being assigned to that column.  Well we can use the double-splat `**` to unpack a dictionary as keyword arguments.  As it happens, I can get such a dictionary from the other dataframe with `df2.to_dict`.  Only, I need to specify that I want that dictionary presented with the `'list'` orientation which I can abbreviate with `'l'`.

**Caveats**
Though this solution is clever, there are some limitations.  As jezrael brings up in the comments.  I'm limited when introducing columns that already exist.  Those columns will be overwritten.  Also, If you have column names that are numeric, it won't work as those column names need to be strings.

---

**Setup**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([list('0123')], list('ABCD')).T.pipe(lambda d: d.radd(d.columns))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(E='E0 E1 E2 E3'.split()), [4, 5, 6, 7])

print(df1, df2, sep='\n\n')

    A   B   C   D
0  A0  B0  C0  D0
1  A1  B1  C1  D1
2  A2  B2  C2  D2
3  A3  B3  C3  D3

    E
4  E0
5  E1
6  E2
7  E3
```

Comment: And also say about limits - not same columns names and not numeric columns names :)